# Change status bar color with private modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

I'm using a light colored status bar `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` and my subclassed navigation bars use a dark color set using the appearance API.

When a private modal view is presented such as "Printer Options" from a `UIActivityViewController` the status bar color stays light so it's not readable with the default navigation bar color.

How do you tell these view controllers to change to a dark status bar color when presented?